# pandas groupby: *full* join result of groupwise operation on original index

Tags: python, pandas, join, pandas-groupby

Consider this `df`:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'id': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C'],
                            'val': [1,2,-3,1,5,6,-2], 
                            'stuff':['12','23232','13','1234','3235','3236','732323']})
```

Question: how to produce a table with as many columns as unique `id` ({A, B, C}) and 
as many rows as `df` where, for example for the column corresponding to `id==A`, the values are:

```
1,
np.nan,
-2,
np.nan,
np.nan,
np.nan,
np.nan
```

(that is the result of `df.groupby('id')['val'].cumsum()` joined on the indexes of `df`).

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: a 7 rows by 3 column matrix, the first column of which is the one show in the question. Do you need the other two columns?

Comment: There was somrthing wrong with last question, so deleted?

Comment: I find solution `print (df.mask(thos_cols.isnull().reindex(index=df.index, columns=df.columns, fill_value=False)))`, this is what need?

Comment: @user189035 hmm, so it seems need something different.

Comment: Then `np.argsort` is good way ;)

Comment: @jezrael: I gave a more precise stab at the question I deleted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52140425/189035)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UMMM `pivot`

```
pd.pivot(df.index,df.id,df.val).cumsum()
Out[33]: 
id    A    B    C    D
0   1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN
2  -2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
4   NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0
5   NaN  8.0  NaN  NaN
6   NaN  NaN -1.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

One way via a dictionary comprehension and [`pd.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
res = pd.DataFrame({i: df['val'].where(df['id'].eq(i)).cumsum() for i in df['id'].unique()})

print(res)

     A    B    C    D
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN
2 -2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0
5  NaN  8.0  NaN  NaN
6  NaN  NaN -1.0  NaN
```

For a small number of groups, you may find this method efficient:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000, ignore_index=True)

def piv_transform(df):
    return pd.pivot(df.index, df.id, df.val).cumsum()

def dict_transform(df):
    return pd.DataFrame({i: df['val'].where(df['id'].eq(i)).cumsum() for i in df['id'].unique()})

%timeit piv_transform(df)   # 17.5 ms
%timeit dict_transform(df)  # 8.1 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly cleaner answers have been supplied - see pivot.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( data = [df.id == x for x in df.id.unique()]).T.mul(df.groupby(['id']).cumsum().squeeze(),axis=0)

df1.columns =df.id.unique()
df1.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if x == 0 else x)


    A    B     C     D
0   1.0  NaN   NaN   NaN
1   NaN  2.0   NaN   NaN
2   -2.0 NaN   NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN   1.0   NaN
4   NaN  NaN   NaN   5.0
5   NaN  8.0   NaN   NaN
6   NaN  NaN   -1.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Short and simple:

```
df.pivot(columns='id', values='val').cumsum()
```