# Collect cells in pandas df that are listed in another pandas df (with same index)

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following example (the two elements of interest are `final_df` and `pivot_df`. The rest of the code is just to construct these two df's):

```
import numpy
import pandas

numpy.random.seed(0)
input_df = pandas.concat([pandas.Series(numpy.round_(numpy.random.random_sample(10,), 2)),
                          pandas.Series(numpy.random.randint(0, 2, 10))], axis = 1) 
input_df.columns = ['key', 'val']


pivot_df = input_df.pivot(columns = 'key', values = 'val')\
                   .fillna(method = 'pad')\
                   .cumsum()

index_df = pivot_df.notnull()\
                   .multiply(pivot_df.columns, axis = 1)\
                   .replace({0.0: numpy.nan})\
                   .values

final_df = numpy.delete(numpy.partition(index_df, 3, axis = 1),
                        numpy.s_[3:index_df.shape[1]], axis = 1)
final_df.sort(axis = 1)            
final_df = pandas.DataFrame(final_df)
```

`final_df` contains as many rows as `pivot_df`. I want to use these two to construct a third df: `bingo_df`.

`bingo_df` should have the same dimensions as `final_df`. Then, the cells of `bingo_df` should contain:

- Whenever the entry `(row = i, col = j)` of  `final_df` is `numpy.nan`,
  the entry `(i,j)` of `bingo_df` should be `numpy.nan` as well.
- Otherwise, [whenever the entry `(i, j)` of  `final_df` is not `numpy.nan`] the entry `(i,j)`  of `bingo_df` should be the value at cell `[i, final_df[i, j].value]` of `pivot_df` (in fact `final_df[i, j].value` is either the name of a column of `pivot_df` or `numpy.nan`)

## Expected ouput:

so the first row of `final_df` is

`0.55,  nan,  nan`.

So I'm expecting the first row of `bingo_df` to be:

`0.0, nan, nan`

because the value in cell `(row = 0, col = 0.55)`  of `pivot_df` is `0`
(and the two subsequent `numpy.nan` in the first row of `final_df` should also be `numpy.nan` in `bingo_df`)

so the second row of `final_df` is

`0.55, 0.72,  nan`

So I'm expecting the second row of `bingo_df` to be:

`0.0, 1.0, nan`

because the value in cell `(row = 1, col = 0.55)` of `pivot_df` is `0.0`
and the value in cell `(row = 1, col = 0.72)` of `pivot_df` is `1.0`

Comment: so what is your expected output ?

Comment: @Wen: added the examples for the first two rows. Scott Boston: fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC `lookup`

```
s=final_df.stack()
pd.Series(pivot_df.lookup(s.index.get_level_values(0),s),index=s.index).unstack()
Out[87]: 
     0    1    2
0  0.0  NaN  NaN
1  0.0  1.0  NaN
2  0.0  1.0  2.0
3  0.0  0.0  2.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0
5  0.0  0.0  0.0
6  0.0  1.0  0.0
7  0.0  2.0  0.0
8  0.0  3.0  0.0
9  0.0  0.0  4.0
```

Comment: @user189035 yw :-) happy coding

Comment: I encounter a problem I am not able to solve. Basically when I remove the `.notnull()` from the example (see edit), I get: `KeyError: 'One or more column labels was not found'` I was wonder if this can be solved?

Comment: @user189035 you can add a if conditions here when error return nan

Comment: ok, just figured this out! Thanks again. Maybe I will roll back my edit to avoid confusion